# What is 0-255 in EEPROM in Arduino?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, eeprom

I am trying to use the EEPROM in Arduino but somehow getting the wrong number. Can anyone explain to me what does that parameter 'value' of 0 to 255(byte) actually mean does it mean it can only hold a value of 255? is it overflowing somehow? if the given number is more that 225?

[image]

I have added my code for reference.
here is the link to the documentation "https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/built-in-libraries/eeprom"

```cpp
#include "EasyNextionLibrary.h" 
#include <EEPROM.h>

#define relayPin 7
#define enPin 8
#define stepPin 10
#define dirPin 9

EasyNex myNex(Serial);

int a = 0;
int value;

int x = myNex.currentPageId;

uint32_t number = 0;
uint32_t lastnumber = 0;

signed int mdelay = 478; 
signed int motorSteps = EEPROM.read(1); //65; //speed
signed int Releasetime = EEPROM.read(2); //100;   //release
signed int Dwelltime = EEPROM.read(3); //75;   //dwell

signed int mo;
signed int Dw;
signed int Re;

int Trig;

int s;
int r;
int d;

#define LOOP_TIME 50
unsigned long timer;

void setup() {
    myNex.begin(9600); 
    timer = millis();

    pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(enPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);

    digitalWrite(enPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH); 
}

void loop() {
    myNex.NextionListen();
    s = EEPROM.read(1);
    r = EEPROM.read(2);
    d = EEPROM.read(3);

    if (myNex.currentPageId != myNex.lastCurrentPageId) {
        if (myNex.currentPageId == 1) {
            myNex.writeNum("n3.val", s);
            myNex.writeNum("n4.val", r);
            myNex.writeNum("n5.val", d);

            myNex.writeNum("n0.val", s);
            myNex.writeNum("n1.val", r);
            myNex.writeNum("n2.val", d);

            motorSteps=s;
            Releasetime=r;
            Dwelltime=d;
        } else if (myNex.currentPageId == 0) {
            myNex.writeNum("n7.val", s);
            myNex.writeNum("n8.val", r);
            myNex.writeNum("n9.val", d);
        }

        myNex.lastCurrentPageId = myNex.currentPageId;
    }

    digitalWrite(enPin, LOW);

    for (int x = 0; x < motorSteps; x++) {
        digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(mdelay);
        digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(mdelay);
    }

    digitalWrite(enPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
    delay(Dwelltime);
    digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
    delay(Releasetime);
}

void trigger1() {
    digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);
}

void trigger2() {
    digitalWrite(dirPin, LOW);
}

void trigger0() {
    Trig=1;

    if ((millis() - timer) > LOOP_TIME) {
        mo = myNex.readNumber("n0.val"); // We read the value of n0 and store it to number variable

        if (number != 777777) {                     // 777777 is the return value if the code fails to read the new value
            lastnumber = number;                  // The chances of getting a wrong value is one in a million.
        } else if (number == 777777) {
            number = lastnumber;
        }    
    }

    myNex.writeNum("n3.val", mo);
    s=mo;

    if ((millis() - timer) > LOOP_TIME) {
        Re = myNex.readNumber("n1.val");   // We read the value of n0 and store it to number variable

        if (number != 777777) {                     // 777777 is the return value if the code fails to read the new value
            lastnumber = number;                  // The chances of getting a wrong value is one in a million.
        } else if (number == 777777) {
            number = lastnumber;
        }
    }

    myNex.writeNum("n4.val", Re);
    Re=mo;

    if ((millis() - timer) > LOOP_TIME) {
        Dw = myNex.readNumber("n2.val");   // We read the value of n0 and store it to number variable

        if (number != 777777) {                     // 777777 is the return value if the code fails to read the new value
            lastnumber = number;                  // The chances of getting a wrong value is one in a million.
        } else if (number == 777777) {
            number = lastnumber;
        }
        timer = millis(); 
    }

    myNex.writeNum("n5.val", Dw);
    d=Dw;
}

void trigger3() {
    s = EEPROM.read(1);
    r = EEPROM.read(2);
    d = EEPROM.read(3);

    if (Trig==1) {
        motorSteps=mo;
        Releasetime=Re;
        Dwelltime=Dw;
        s=mo;
        r=Re;
        d=Dw;
        EEPROM.update(1, s);
        EEPROM.update(2, r);
        EEPROM.update(3, d);
        Trig=0;
    } 
    else {
        motorSteps=s;
        Releasetime=r;
        Dwelltime=d;
    }
}

void trigger4() {
    s = EEPROM.read(1);
    r = EEPROM.read(2);
    d = EEPROM.read(3);

    if (myNex.currentPageId != myNex.lastCurrentPageId) {
        if (myNex.currentPageId == 1) {
            myNex.writeNum("n0.val", s);
            myNex.writeNum("n1.val", r);
            myNex.writeNum("n2.val", d);
            EEPROM.update(1, s);
            EEPROM.update(2, r);
            EEPROM.update(3, d);
        }

        myNex.lastCurrentPageId = myNex.currentPageId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking what's the maximum decimal value that can be stored in one byte? Any beginner learning material ought to address that very early on.

Comment: As for the variable `number`, the code posted doesn't appear to write to that variable. Unless it is done through spaghetti programming with `extern`, then it will remain zero.

Comment: no, I was looking for the reason it overflowed. I am so sorry, I did a rooky misunderstanding,  it says 0-255 which is basically  256. I don't have the full code here, I am passing it to a display and didn't account for that. thank you for your time.

Comment: spaghetti programming hilarious @Lundin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write a byte to the EEPROM, you are only writing 8 bits. As an unsigned integer, that will only store a lowest value of 00000000 = 0 and a highest value of 11111111 = 255.

It depends what the compiler does if you ask it to store a wider number. Ideally you will get a warning or error, as you are passing the wrong type into the byte_write function, but some might just silently store the 8 least significant bits, effectively doing a mod 256 to your larger number.

The correct way to store a large integer to EEPROM with this library is to break it up into bytes (and reconstruct it from bytes when you read it back). There are a number of ways you can do that, depending on your programming inclinations. You could repeatedly right-shift and mask, or you could define a byte struct aliased with the larger integer, and I'm sure there are a few other ways as well. You might even find some helper functions in the EEPROM library designed for this specific purpose, or as @Juraj points out, other functions in the library can write larger variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it really helps to clear a rooky misunderstanding. Thank you!!

Comment: Unions might be pretty useful.

Comment: the Arduino EEPROM library can write more bytes at once. for example a complete struct. https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/built-in-libraries/eeprom#put . `put` and `get` are  template functions